# How do you choose to compute partials with the adjoint method?

Tags: openmdao

Is there a specific option? Can you choose forward or reverse mode? Does it not matter since under the hood openMDAO computes the derivatives with the unified method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Problem.setup` you can include the argument `mode` which is one of `fwd', 'rev', or 'auto'.

Note that the choice of forward or reverse (adjoint) derivatives affects how *total* derivatives (the ones that the optimizers and solvers need) are computed from the partial derivatives (the ones the provided by the components). It does not affect how the partial derivatives are provided in the `compute_partials` or `linearize` methods though.

Choosing the correct mode can make a big difference in performance, and in most use cases 'auto' will figure out the correct mode based on the number of design variables and the number of constraints + objective.

Problems with many constraints and few design variables (many rows, few columns in the total jacobian) will usually be much faster in forward mode.

Those with few constraints but many design variables (few rows, many columns) will be significantly faster in reverse.

**Advanced Bidirectional Derivatives**

OpenMDAO will also attempt to figure out the fastest way to compute totals through "coloring" the total jacobian.  The analogy of this is, in finite-difference, sometimes you can perturb multiple design variables simultaneously to speed the calculation of the jacobian, assuming these variables don't both contribute to the same constraints/objective.

Traditionally, if a total jacobian had a dense column, then it can't efficiently be colored in reverse mode (multiple constraints "impact" the same design variable).

Similarly, a dense row would kill the efficiency of coloring the jacobian in forward mode.

However, OpenMDAO can figure out which derivatives can be efficiently colored in forward mode, and which can be colored in reverse mode, using both approaches to fill in the total jacobian.

You can read more about this capability here:  http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.0.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/simul_derivs.html